# Record and count touch inputs in the background

Tags: java, android, input, service, touch

Working on an app that records and displays the number of touches in the app and in the background as a service. It should also detect and record touches when other apps are running.

What would be the best approach to get this working? I'm currently using onUserInteraction method in the app to count the touches, but not sure about the service.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    // super.onUserInteraction();        
    click++;

    String clicksString = Integer.toString(click);
    clickTextView.setText(clicksString);
}
```

Can this method be used in the background service or should I look for something else like MotionEvent, etc.?

Comment: You may want to consider: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/